# Cálculo Average True Range

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemática

Estou com o seguinte problema: realizei o cálculo do ATR (Average True Range) utilizando a biblioteca numpy, não houve nenhum problema de código (exceção, etc...) porém, o resultado apresenta uma pequena diferença decimal, quando comparado a um software que também realiza este cálculo. Há alguma outra biblioteca que calcule também calcule o ATR? Ou alguma outra biblioteca que seja voltada para o mercado financeiro? Agradeço.

Comment: De quanto foi esta diferença? Ela será significativa? Qual é o código que você utilizou?

Comment: Leia isso aqui: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Opa, tranquilo? Consegui resolver, era só questão de afinação mesmo. Mas a título de curiosidade, utilizei como base o código do livro do numpy 3 edição (http://pdf.th7.cn/down/files/1602/NumPy,%203rd%20Edition.pdf). Agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem você dizer de quanto é a diferença, é impossível responder essa pergunta com certeza -  mas o mais provável é que a diferença seja devido ao erro natural decorrente de como representamos os números em plataformas computacionais.  Entender esse artigo é fundamental:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Agora,  em geral a biblioteca numpy vai  dar resultados corretos - mesmo por que bastaria uma pessoa encontrando um erro real de cálculo - como o que você teme ter encontrado, para se abrir um ["bug report" no projeto](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20%20atr%20), já que ele é aberto na internet, e coisa ser ou resolvida ou bem documentada em pouco tempo. (Já com programas comerciais esse ciclo é bem mais complicado - mesmo que haja uma forma de contato do vendedor para reportar defeitos, os mesmos não são visíveis quer para o púbico quer para outros assinantes do software).

Assim sendo, não, não acredito que seja um "erro" no numpy, mas, sobretudo, num mundo colaborativo que é viabilizado na medida em que se pode ter acesso direto aos desenvolvedores do software, uma mudança fundamental que precisamos ter é de "esse nao funciona, deixa eu usar outro" - o numpy é mais que uma biblitoeca- é ma plataforma para computações numéricas que evolui há uns 20 anos para Python, e baseada em bibitoecas numéricas em código nativo que existem e são usadas por miçhoes de pessoas há talvez duas vezes esse tempo.  Mesmo que fosse um erro no numpy, a atitude de "este projeto está quebrado, deixe eu usar outro", não seria a melhor solução: podemos ajudar a arrumar aqui.  (Claro, tudo com bom senso - pode ser uqe haja uma biblioteca especializada em cálculos financeiros, que evolua mais rápido que o numpy justamente por ser mais focada, etc... )